# SQL Server constraint not deleting

Tags: sql-server

So, first off, we're using a history system where there's a history version of all of our tables. I'm adding a new column to a table, so I add it to both the dbo and the hist versions. I add a constraint that the default should be 0. However, I misspelled the column for the hist table. So, I add the correct one, and go to drop the incorrect one. However, it's saying `The object 'DF__FCRelease__NumRe_125D4E50' is dependent on column 'NumRelease'.` This is the constraint I mentioned above. I've tried deleting it though SQL, which claims it completes successfully, but the constraint remains. I've tried deleting it through the GUI, but it claims the object does not exist. Here's the SQL I attempted to use to delete the constraint:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[DF__FCRelease__NumRe__125D4E50]') AND type = 'D')
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE [hist].[FCRelease] DROP CONSTRAINT [DF__FCRelease__NumRe__125D4E50]
END
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try running just the alter statement ALTER TABLE [hist].[FCRelease] DROP CONSTRAINT [DF__FCRelease__NumRe__125D4E50]
? Also where are you seeing that the constraint still remains. If you're using the object explorer you may need to refresh your display.

Comment: Are you sure you are running in the right database context?

Comment: I think I tried just the alter statement, but I did refresh the display. It may have been a problem with the correct database context. When my coworker tried it, he got it to delete, even though he was doing the same things I was, it worked for him.

Answer (score 0):

This, I believe, is related to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7116839/425809).  So, I'll give you a similar answer.

You probably need [rebuild your master database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143269(v=sql.90).aspx).  I suspect that there is some corruption there that is causing this issue.

As a workaround, you could try removing the column, re-adding it, and then re-adding the constraint (a la [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116839/can-not-delete-or-modify-or-see-same-table-foreign-key-constraint/7150820#7150820)).  That might fix the problem as well.