# Can not delete or modify or see same table foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, foreign-key-relationship

A same table foreign key constraint in my database is not accessible. I can not drop it, disable it, add it back, ... How do I remove it and re-add it?

Note: I have several versions of my database all created with the same script. Only in one I see this behavior. In others, this key is easily added and removed.

Many thanks. Here is some scripts I ran and the result:

At some point in the past i ran the following script:

```
ALTER TABLE Recipe
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Recipe_DuplicateOfRecipeId_Recipe_Id FOREIGN KEY (DuplicateOfRecipeId)
    REFERENCES Recipe (Id) ;
```

now running

```
ALTER TABLE Recipe DROP CONSTRAINT  FK_Recipe_DuplicateOfRecipeId_Recipe_Id 
results in the following error:
'FK_Recipe_DuplicateOfRecipeId_Recipe_Id' is not a constraint.
```

and running

```
ALTER TABLE Recipe NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK_Recipe_DuplicateOfRecipeId_Recipe_Id
results in: Constraint 'FK_Recipe_DuplicateOfRecipeId_Recipe_Id' does not exist.
```

so i run

```
alter table Recipe ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Recipe_DuplicateOfRecipeId_Recipe_Id FOREIGN KEY (DuplicateOfRecipeId) REFERENCES Recipe (Id);
```

and i get:

```
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint "FK_Recipe_DuplicateOfRecipeId_Recipe_Id". The conflict occurred in database "CrawlerDB", table "dbo.Recipe", column 'Id'.
```

so I run:

```
select COUNT(*) from sys.objects where name = 'FK_Recipe_DuplicateOfRecipeId_Recipe_Id'
select COUNT(*) from sys.all_objects where name = 'FK_Recipe_DuplicateOfRecipeId_Recipe_Id'
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.foreign_keys where name = 'FK_Recipe_DuplicateOfRecipeId_Recipe_Id'
```

and all 3 return nothing.

Whats going on and how do I fix it? I need to access this object, remove it and add it back.
Many thanks!

Comment: Any difference between the results of sp_help 'recipe'; and sp_help 'dbo.recipe'; ?

Comment: after setting all values in the foreign key field to null, then everything works again. But why?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly "works again" when you clear that column? You can drop the constraint, or just create it, or nocheck, or your queries against the metadata tables suddenly start returning 1, or...?

Comment: @aaron after setting the foreign key field to null, running these alternatively works: 
ALTER TABLE Recipe DROP CONSTRAINT  FK_Recipe_DuplicateOfRecipeId_Recipe_Id
alter table Recipe ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Recipe_DuplicateOfRecipeId_Recipe_Id FOREIGN KEY (DuplicateOfRecipeId) REFERENCES Recipe (Id);

I am not quite sure which one worked first, but going back and forth between them now I can recreate the constraint and drop it

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me, especially the part about the system object queries (hence my sp_help suggestion - thought there might have been schema mixup since you're not always properly schema-prefixing). I'm not convinced you have a handle on your order of operations during the initial problem or after the "solution" - changing data does not make constraints disappear and re-appear.

Comment: I was writing a script that was removing the constraint doing some stuff and then adding the constraint. But is order of operation even an issue here. if the constraint is already there, adding it again should give me an error that it already exists. And if it has already been dropped, dropping it again should send me the error that it does not exist. In either scenario there is a consistent error message or result that one expects.  the results above are outside of that range of reason.

Comment: Ok, well I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. SQL Server was not playing tricks on you and behaving differently for kicks; I still think the order you remember running things and the order you actually ran them might not be 100% consistent. And yes, order does matter.

Comment: I know. That is why I posted here so someone who is smarter than me could tell me what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that your master database is corrupted.  You'd probably be best suited by [rebuilding it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143269%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

However, as a workaround, you could try this:

1. Duplicate your foreign key into a non-FK column

   `ALTER TABLE Recipe ADD DuplicateOfFK INT`
2. Copy all your FK data to the duplicate

   `UPDATE Recipe SET DuplicateOfFK = DuplicateOfRecipeId`
3. Drop the Foreign Key column

   `ALTER TABLE Recipe DROP COLUMN DuplicateOfRecipeId`
4. Go backwards.

   `ALTER TABLE Recipe ADD DuplicateOfRecipeId INT`

   `UPDATE Recipe SET DuplicateOfRecipeId = DuplicateOfFK`

   `ALTER TABLE Recipe DROP COLUMN DuplicateOfFK`
5. Add the constraint back.

Comment: I think rebuilding the database is a great idea.  i did a a similar workaround for now. But will definitely try it when it starts giving me trouble next, which I have a feeling it will. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your comment above should have given you the clue:

> after setting all values in the foreign key field to null, then
>   everything works again. But why?

Unfortunately the error message can be misleading. The statement adding the foreign key back failed not because you were creating a circular reference, but because DuplicateOfRecipeId contained at least one non-null value that was not already contained in Id.

By that I mean that the following code works:

```
create table dbo.Recipe
(
    Id int not null identity(1, 1)
        constraint PK_Recipe primary key nonclustered
    , DuplicateOfRecipeId int not null
);
insert dbo.Recipe values (1), (2), (3);
alter table Recipe add constraint FK_Recipe_DuplicateOfRecipeId_Recipe_Id foreign key (DuplicateOfRecipeId) references Recipe (Id);
drop table dbo.Recipe
go
```

But the following code fails (note the different DuplicateOfRecipeId values):

```
create table dbo.Recipe
(
    Id int not null identity(1, 1)
        constraint PK_Recipe primary key nonclustered
    , DuplicateOfRecipeId int not null
);
insert dbo.Recipe values (4), (5), (6);
alter table Recipe add constraint FK_Recipe_DuplicateOfRecipeId_Recipe_Id foreign key (DuplicateOfRecipeId) references Recipe (Id);
drop table dbo.Recipe
go
```